# Ruby and Rail - How to combine date and time to get data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I have 3 columns : booking_date, booking_time_from, booking_time_to.

Problem is how can i get all data have booking time 2 hours ago using Active Support ?

```
Booking.where([booking_time], 2.hours.ago.to_datetime)
```

Comment: I think the below answer from Vincent should help. Please elaborate your question if it doesn;t work for you.

Comment: Question is unclear. What is your final goal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what's the difference between `booking_time_from` and `booking_time_to`, and which column that the booking time you're referring here. Let's assume it's `booking_time_to`, you can

```rb
Booking.where("booking_time_to < ?", 2.hours.ago)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
booking_date is just date type,
booking_time_from is just date time,
booking_time_to is just date time.
I want to combine booking_date & booking_time_to to get data 2 hours ago.

Comment: or `Booking.where(booking_time: ...2.hours.ago)` using beginless ranges